# Slice a big File into parts and merge it on a server side

Tags: javascript, angularjs, file-upload, angular-file-upload

i have to slice a file and send its parts into a server apiRest side save each part on a database and when the last part is on server merge to create the complete file.
Why do i use a database? because i have a server farm environment
client side is angularjs with angularfileUpaloadi was thinking to send partNumber, token and otalPart with each part. Do we have any javascript api?

My last question are two. How do i create thoses part to send? and How do i merge its parts on c# side?

Comment: My problem is not read into memory this file is send it.

Comment: You are asking two different questions. Each question should be a single problem. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader If you show what you have tried, you are much more likely to get meaningful help, if you haven't tried anything, the question is too open ended.